# Hide part of a child element

Tags: css, shadow

Expected result is a DIV with a shadow behind:

[image: preview]

I am using box-shadow and border-radius to make it bend.

The DIV cannot have a background. I know it would be easy if it had a bg because I could just play with z-indexes. Also, the height of the DIV is not fixed (it depends on the content).

Is there some other way I could cut a part of the pseudo-element ? Some kind of reverse `overflow:hidden` ?

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  test
</div>
```

Comment: maybe you don't know `clip-path` ?

Comment: Does the div can have a background white?

Comment: nvm, I managed to do it with a combination of elliptical radial-gradient and 2x background-size